# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Resources on Minimalist Style of Creative Writing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8486/resources-on-minimalist-style-of-creative-writing)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Using pronouns properly in order to avoid confusion and repetition](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8313/using-pronouns-properly-in-order-to-avoid-confusion-and-repetition)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is it common for flashbacks to not to follow a chronological order?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8505/is-it-common-for-flashbacks-to-not-to-follow-a-chronological-order)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Opening a story with a reference to what someone just said followed by a setting description](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8263/opening-a-story-with-a-reference-to-what-someone-just-said-followed-by-a-setting)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Permission requirements from people in my memoir](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/permission-requirements-from-people-in-my-memoir)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Metrics for assessing the persuasiveness of a paper?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8378/metrics-for-assessing-the-persuasiveness-of-a-paper)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Attributing quotes to fictional characters](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8440/attributing-quotes-to-fictional-characters)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How do I improve my knowledge of English well enough to write in it?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8423/how-do-i-improve-my-knowledge-of-english-well-enough-to-write-in-it)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Do people read short stories?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8318/do-people-read-short-stories)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What steps can be taken to avoid libel / copyright issues in social commentary?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8320/what-steps-can-be-taken-to-avoid-libel-copyright-issues-in-social-commentary)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)